# Benefits Gained by Passing WebControls By Ref

Tags: c#, asp.net, language-features

Are there any performance benefits to be gained from passing objects like WebControls by ref? I'm specifically thinking of such things as validation methods that modify a control's  look & feel (background-color, CSSClass etc.) ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope. The only benefit of passing a reference type variable by reference is if you want to be able to change the value of the caller's variable, i.e. change which object it refers to. For example:

```
// Creates a new label if necessary, and sets the text to Stuff
public void Foo(ref Label label)
{
    if (label == null)
    {
        label = new Label();
    }
    label.Text = "Stuff";
}
```

Personally I try to avoid `ref` where possible: it *tends* to indicate that the method is doing too much.

Comment: @Jon, Am I missing something? If it's a reference type why would you *ever* need to pass it by `ref`? Wouldn't the example you gave work just fine without `ref`?

Comment: @Brad: No, it wouldn't... because if the caller's variable was null beforehand, it would be null afterwards if you didn't use ref. See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: PS. @JonSkeet - excuse my ignorance - are you the same Jon Skeet who wrote 'C# In Depth'? I'm looking at your astronomical SO score and guessing you are ....

Comment: @5arx: Yup, that's me. Fortunately there aren't many people called "Jon Skeet" around :)

Comment: @MrSkeet - I'm honoured that you answered my question. That book is the dog's bollocks - if I ever get round to reading it all I probably won't ever have to ask facile questions like this  :-(

Comment: @Jon, why have the ref in the first place since if this is a reference type, whatever changes are made will change the original object value anyways, precisely of the reference type nature?

Comment: @Max: See Jon's reply to Brad's earlier post.

Answer (score 2):

When you do a

```
Button btn = new Button();
```

the btn variable is not the newly created button, instead it's a reference to the button.
So if I want to have a method that makes a buttons text bold, this is enough:

```
public void MakeButtonBold(Button button)
{
  button.Font.Bold = true;
}
```

because, even if the method uses pass-by-value, I get a copy of the reference to the button. Then when I dereference it using the `.` operator, the object I get is the same, since both the reference outside the method and it's copy within the method point to the same object.

However if I do something like this

```
public void ReplaceButtonWithBold(Button button)
{
  button = new Button();
  button.Font.Bold = true;
}
```

it wont work, because I discarded the passed reference, when I set it to a new button.

In contrast, when I use a ref parameter, then a reference is created to the variable that is used for the parameter, and that reference is passed to method. So if `ReplaceButtonWithBold` used a `ref` parameter, my code would work as intended.

So, the rule of thumb should be only to use ref parameters if you explicitly want to replace the **whole** passed object with something different, and not when you want to change some properties.
From a performance perspective, a normal method needs to make a copy of the reference, and the ref method need to make a new reference to the original reference, so either way you have to use time and memory to create and manage a reference

Comment: I take it then that I can safely assume the overhead of making a copy of the reference I pass in a method call is minimal?

Comment: Yes, it's minimal, but not more than creating a new reference, so the performance is practically the same with or without ref.

Answer (score 1):

No, no performance benefits.

As these are *already* reference types, this is not needed and will only make your code more cumbersome to write and use.

Answer (score 1):

It is highly unlikely for this to ever matter, but below is some code I played with to test this:

```
public class popo
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}

public static bool foo(popo x)
{
    x.X = 10;
    return x.X == x.Y;
}

public static bool foo(ref popo x)
{
    x.X = 10;
    return x.X == x.Y;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Stop();
    sw.Reset();
    sw.Start();
    popo pio = new popo();
    bool luka = true;
    for (long i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
    {
        luka = luka ^ foo(pio);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Trace.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Results (in milliseconds):

```
Release Val: 948
Release Ref: 1065  
Debug Val: 2451  
Debug Ref: 2550
```

Obviously this is not real code.  There could be situations where passing a reference type by reference is faster.  There are cases where using a faster CPU can slow your application down.  Still, this does provide a quick and dirty hint that ref will probably be a little slower.  It also demonstrates that it doesn't matter: look how many iterations I needed to get to see even a ~100 ms difference in execution time.

It is highly unlikely that the efficiency of ref vs. value for classes will be relevant to your code.

Comment: You, Sir are a scientist!

Despite having the legendary Jon Skeet answer this it was nagging away  a bit (like I don't have enough to worry about). Thanks for proving it :-)